# RavenDB 3.0 LIKE Query

Tags: ravendb

I am using `RavenDB Embedded 3.0` and have document `Customer` and its data as follow:

> ID                                   Name
>
> ---
>
> customers/101              Leo
>
> customers/102              Leo Chan
>
> customers/103              Leo Lee
>
> customers/104              Special Name?

I want to perform a SQL like `LIKE '%keyword%'` search on the field `Name` (the keyword can contains special character, and case insensitive), take below three test cases as example:

1. If the keyword is `Leo` (or `eo`, or `EO`), it returns the records `customers/101 Leo`, `customers/102 Leo Chan` and `customers/103 Leo Lee`.
2. If the keyword is `Leo Chan` (or `Leo Ch`, or `eo Ch`, or `EO ch`), then the only result is `customers/102 Leo Chan`.
3. If the keyword is `?`, only the last record `customers/104 Special Name?` will be returned (the question mark `?` in the keyword will not act as wildcard for my case, it is just a normal text to be searched for).

How can I implement above logic in RavenDB 3.0? Please forgive me that I am new to RavenDB and not familiar with Lucene, it is appreciate that provide the detail code for reference. Thanks in advanced!

**EDIT**

In order to describe the problem clearer, following showing the code I am using, it only passed the test case #1 listed above.

The entity and index:

```
class Customer {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Customers_ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Customer> {
    public Customers_ByName() {
        Map = customers => from customer in customers
                           select new {
                               customer.Name
                           };

        Indexes.Add(c => c.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And the search snippet:

```
var keyword = "Leo Chan";
var query = string.Format("*{0}*", QueryParser.Escape(keyword).Replace(" ", @"\ "));
var list = session.Query<Customer, Customers_ByName>()
    .Search(c => c.Name, query, escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards)
    .ToList();
    
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);  // 0
```

And the index definition in the database

```
from doc in docs.Customers
select new {
    Name = doc.Name
}
```

[image: Index: Customers/ByName]

Answer (score 0):

You can't in standard IQueryable LINQ - Ayende (Raven's creator) doesn't believe you should do that (he calls it "Safe by Default"). You need to set up a custom index and use that in your query:

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/querying/searching

See the part about "Safe by Default" and Search/Escaping.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your information! I agree the "Safe by Default" concept, but I do believe that my requirement is common and from user's perspective, it is helpful and convenient for searching. For the performance issue, I think slow is better than nothing, right? I have updated my post to include the code I am using for reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* use a query such as '*foo*' to do the same work as like, we will strongly discourage that.

You want to use the full text search feature:

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/indexes/using-analyzers
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-use-search

Comment: Hi Ayende, thanks for your information, it do help to understand the behavior of Analyzer. However, I tried to use the KeywordAnalyzer and other analyzers listed in that document, and also tried to change the field to NotAnalyzed, but still cannot achieve my goal (the three test cases listed above). May I know if I have to write a custom analyzer in order to do that? I am sorry I am not familiar with Lucene.

Comment: You need to mark the field as Analyzed, not NotAnalyzed